# Python count words under certain condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the seccond word of each line but only if the seccond last number is 0 in a csv and count how many times each of them words appear in the csv file.

data:

```
0;London ;150;0;9
```

code so far:

```
words= []
with open('the_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
         csv_words = row[1].split(";")
         for i in csv_words:
              words.append(i)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Hey Tom, it might pay to include what output you are currently getting as well as some more sample data.

Comment: You could save yourself a bit of code by adding `delimiter=';'` in the reader declaration.

Comment: `valid_lines = filter(lambda l: l.split(";")[-2] != "0", lines); print(collections.Counter(line.split(";")[1].strip() for line in  valid_lines))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the way you're checking the value of the second last field, as you currently check element `1` of the string, which is `;` and then proceed to split by `;`.

```
test = '0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9'
>>> test[1].split(';')
['', '']
```

In relation to counting words, utilising a dictionary over a list here will provide a much easier solution.

Enlarged file;

```
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;2;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;3;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;Sydney ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
```

Code

```
import csv

words = {} # Create empty dict

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'r') as file:

    for row in file.readlines(): # For each line in csv
        data = row.split(";") # Split each row by ;
        if int(data[3]) == 0: # Cast second last element as int() and check if == 0
            if data[1] in words: # If London has been seen before, increment counter
                words[data[1].strip()] += 1
            else: # If it has not been seen before, create it as a key and + 1 count
                words[data[1].strip()] = 1

print(words)
```

Output

```
{'London': 5, 'Sydney': 1}
```

As a note, if it is possible that the second last element will not be an integer, you would need to change the `if statement` to either a `try/catch` clause or to just cast 0 as a `str` instead.

```
if data[3] == str(0):
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the split to occur on the entire row, instead of just on the third character (row[3].split(';') changed to row.split(';'))

```
words= []
with open('the_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        csv_words = row.split(";")
        if csv_words[3] == '0':
            words.append(csv_words[1].strip())
print(words)
# ['London']

words_counted = []
for i in words:
    x = words.count(i)
    words_counted.append((i,x))
print(words_counted)
# [('London', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a lot and achieve the same objective. I've used the Counter module from collections to simplify this.

Sample CSV. Added the fourth row with 1 in the second last column to make sure my answer does not count that.

```
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;1;9
0;London ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;Tampa ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;Tampa ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
0;Tampa ;10-05-2019 08:50:00;0;9
```

Code:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

words= []
with open('the_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[-2:][0]) == 0:
            words.append(row[1])


Counter(words)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'London ': 4, 'Tampa ': 3})
```

Things I did:

1) Added a delimiter `;` to `reader` i.e. `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')`

2) Cast the second last element to a `int` in the list to check for 0 i.e. `if int(row[-2:][0]) == 0:`

3) Used the `Counter` module to do the counting for me from the list `words`

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict` so you can use the `Counter` in some similar ways as a dictionary.

**Shorter Version**

You can avoid the list `words` altogether with the following code:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

word_count = Counter()
with open('the_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[-2:][0])== 0:
            word_count.update([row[1]]) 

print(word_count)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'London ': 4, 'Tampa ': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Counter object (in collections) will do all that work for you:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('the_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    words = Counter(word.strip() for _,word,_,flag,_ in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';') if flag == "0")

words["london"] # ---> number of times london was found
```